# HDMI Audio Not Working

Tags: sound, 64-bit, hdmi, 16.10, amd-graphics

Running Ubuntu 16.10 and I connected my 32in TV to my R9 380. The display is working, but I am not getting audio.  It works on Windows. I have tried PulseAudio Volume Control and it did not help.

Comment: Also sound works out of my blue yeti mic, so the issue seems limited to HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

Had to revert to 16.04 and install AMDGPU-Pro to get HDMI audio to work.  Thanks for the help awesome community.  Too bad I cannot be on the bleeding edge.